# Im getting the "nonetype" error but i cant figure out why

Tags: python, mysql, error-handling, typeerror, nonetype

so i basically know what the Error means but i don't know why i'm getting it.I want to insert my cvs file into a table. Some of the rows are empty, thats why im using the if None...

The Error im getting:

File "C:\Users\Desktop\IngestData.py", line 64, in institutions
    cokey = temp[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Hope somebody can help me!
Thank you in advance!

```
def institutions(cur):
    with open('persons.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as g:
        #tempo = None
        reader = csv.reader(g)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            if row[4] is None:
                break
            else:
                cur.execute("SELECT COKEY FROM countries WHERE Name = (%s)", [row[4]])
                temp = cur.fetchone()
                cokey = temp[0]
                cur.execute("""INSERT INTO institutions (Name,cokey) VALUES (%s,%s)
                            ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;""",[row[3],cokey])
```

Comment: print temp after line: temp = cur.fetchone()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your database have any matching rows? `cur.fetchone()` is returning `None`, that's why your error is saying that `NoneType is not suscriptable`.

```py
def institutions(cur):
    with open('persons.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as g:
        #tempo = None
        reader = csv.reader(g)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            if row[4] is None:
                break
            else:
                cur.execute("SELECT COKEY FROM countries WHERE Name = (%s)", [row[4]])
                temp = cur.fetchone()
                if temp:
                    cokey = temp[0]
                    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO institutions (Name,cokey) VALUES (%s,%s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;""",[row[3],cokey])
```

Comment: yeah it does. But shouldn't it iterate over the empty rows because of the if statement? It should continue if there is None, so it should fetch only the rows where countries are available

Comment: Doesn't matter if `row[4] is not None` if there is not a value inside the database that matches that `row[4]` value. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

change the line `if row[4] is None` condition to `if row[4] is not None` like this:

```
for row in reader:
    if row[4] is not None:
        cur.execute("SELECT COKEY FROM countries WHERE Name = (%s)", [row[4]])
                temp = cur.fetchone()
                cokey = temp[0]
                cur.execute("""INSERT INTO institutions (Name,cokey) VALUES (%s,%s)
                            ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;""",[row[3],cokey])
```